# c++ / visual studio Почему в стандартном контейнере отображаются size и capacity, а в моём нет?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Создал вектор, у него всегда в окне локальных переменных есть поля [allocator] и [capacity] (см. картинку), к тому же видно все элементы этого вектора [0], [1.], [2.], ....
Но почему, если я создаю свой контейнер, то в нём уже этого не видно? (практически скопировал его из std::vector изменил и добавил пару методов).

На скриншоте раскрыт первый элемент (мой контейнер), но у него не видно ни allocator-a, ни capacity, ни всех его элементов. А последнее могло бы помочь с отладкой.

### Почему так, собственно, происходит?

- Visual Studio поддерживает отображение только для стандартных
  контейнеров?
- Или я что-то не скопировал из стандартного вектора?
- Или есть что-то очень хитрое, что нужно сделать для отображения элементов, о чём я не знаю?
- А может у меня руки кривые просто?

Я думаю, что многие хотели бы видеть все элементы своего контейнера при отладке, но если это невозможно, это может расстроить парочку программистов =(

> P.s. stop animal abuse

В любом случае, я очень жду ваших размышлений.

---

### Картиночка для привлечения ответов

[image: Скриншот кода]

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2019

Comment: Тут еще стоит добавить, что нельзя просто так скопировать код из стандартной библиотеки.